# How to create a Printer for PDF printing with user rights in windows?

Tags: windows, security, pdf, printing

We have problems with our PDF creating solution in terminal server environments.
On Creating PDF a PDF printer must be created and destroyed, but a normal user has no rights to do that. Is there an oppurtunity to create a Printer in the user Session without using a print server?

Comment: Your aplication strategy to output PDF is to create and destroy a windows printer under the hood? Ouch!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a Windows service that can print PDF files and install it on the server. The service should be made to watch a folder for files uploaded by the terminal user and then print them as per his/her requirements. As a Windows service is handling the printing, it would have no rights problem.

Comment: We have Problems to get Report Data out of the Powerbuilder Application without using Printer. So this does not solve the Problem :-(

Comment: why is the PDF creating solution creating a PDF printer queue each time? Can you elaborate a little more on the PB application since that seems to be doing this.